# Ways to speed up HTML site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, .htaccess

I am constantly adding stuff to my site and when I do it gets slower.

Things I did:

- Minify JS, CSS, HTML
- Use a CDN (for jquery and other popular libraries)
- GZIP Compression
- .htaccess stuff
- Image Compression
- HTML5 Header Cache
- [Headjs](http://headjs.com)

My site on Pingdom:

[image: Speed Test]

What other stuff can I do to speed it up and make it smaller (use less bandwidth also).

Thanks!

PS. I can offer some code if you want.

Edit:

YSlow:

[image: YSlow]

Comment: If it is pulling data from somewhere, have the page load without the data, and then use AJAX to load the part that has the data.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Run tests on sites like gtmetrix or yslow. IMHO this question is too broad and generic, and it welcomes opinion-based answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify when is your website slow - the load time, or post-load time. I'll briefly discuss both cases:

### Load time

The biggest delay I see is the server waiting time. That could be cause by many things - a far away server, bad/cheap server, a lot of (unoptimized) database communications, etc.

Next, I've noticed a 400KB image. Although you said you've done image compression, that's still a pretty big size, so I hope it's a huge image that you might be panning or some other justified purpose. If it's just a regular background image (say, HD resolution), you better bring it down to at least a half. Since you're doing a responsive site, you can also consider serving different images for different devices/screen sizes.

Next I see a few css and js files, some yours and the other are third-party. You could consider merging those together, there are many great deployment tools that can do that.

But even if you do all of the above, don't expect too much. Based on what you've said, you're already very close to the maximal optimization, so all this would be shaving off a couple dozens of milliseconds each.

---

### Post-load time

Drop all JS you don't need! Yes, it includes jQuery, headJS, everything... and copy/rewrite the parts you actually use. Of course, this doesn't make sense in case you're using like 95% of jQuery's features, which nobody does.

Be careful with event listeners, make sure you're targetting elements properly.

Comment: Just saying with the image compression all the compresses at 400kb did ot go any further if any like less than 1%

Comment: The sky image is already noisy - I compressed it at around 50% and ended up with a 198KB (which is nearly 50% size of the original) file and it does not seem noisier, just the noise patterns are different. See it here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=49127213706142573104

Comment: Btw. why is that image never cached? Every time I refresh the page, I see the image reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your JS imports at the end of your page (before closing body tag) instead of putting these inside the head tag at the begining. 
Example:

```
<html>
<body>
//other declarations
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/myscript.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It will reduce the time to load your page.

Comment: Thanks but, I did that